# Doubts about logging with several modules

Tags: python, logging

I'm developing a simple CLI tool to automate some tasks. My project is structured in the following way

```
my-app/
├─ sub-module-1/
│  ├─ __init__.py
│  ├─ sub-module-1.py
├─ main.py
```

The `main.py` file is the entry point. It accepts and parses several options from the command line. The idea is that it should accept one parameter to modify the log level of the **whole** application (think about that as a `--log-level debug/info/error`, `--verbose`, etc.).

The `main.py` file is defining its own logger (calling `logging.getLogger(__name__)`).

To perform its tasks, the `main.py` file is immediately importing the `sub-module-1.py` module (i.e. at the top of the file). The `__init__.py` in the `sub-module-1` directory has some log lines as well, so it's also defining its own `logging.getLogger(__name__)`.

My problem is that the logging statements in the `__init__.py` are executed **before** the parsing of the parameters in the `main.py` file, so they are simply ignoring the log level that is set accordingly to the input parameter read by the main file.

What is a good way to revisit the structure of my application? One thing that I can do is to import the `sub-module-1.py` later, **after** reading the input parameters, but I'm not sure this is a good way (yes, it works, but I don't personally like the idea of having the `import` statements mixed with the rest of the code).

Answer (score 0):

one way to do this is to explicitly import all loggers and call `logger.setLevel`

Comment: Could you please elaborate more?

Answer (score 0):

let's say you have loggers in different modules which have one or more handlers attached to them,
import them all into `main.py` and add them to a list called `loggers`.
Then do:

```
for logger in loggers:
    for handler in logger.handlers:
        handler.setLevel(<level>)
```

Note: for this to work each logger has to have at least one handler attached to it

if you don't know how to add handlers then you need to check this out https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logging.Logger.addHandler

Comment: But even if I do that, in the `main.py` AFTER the `sub-module-1.__init__.py` has been already executed (because of the import on the top) that would be too late.

Comment: then you have to make the import after reading the argument variables then maybe set an environment variable that the remaining modules can read from.

Comment: And this is what I would do... but I'm not sure if there are advantages/disadvantages in importing the modules later...